# kafka broker not available at starting

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka

I set on a ubuntu node of a cluster a kafka 0.11.0.0 instance.
Until some weeks ago everything worked fine, today I'm trying to starting it and I obtain this error after the boot:

```
[2017-09-11 16:21:13,894] INFO [Kafka Server 0], started (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-09-11 16:21:18,998] WARN Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2017-09-11 16:21:21,991] WARN Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
... and so on...
```

My server.properties:

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

# Switch to enable topic deletion or not, default value is false
delete.topic.enable=true

############################# Socket Server Settings ##########################$

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If no$
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the $
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://hidden_ip:55091
```

I edited advertised.listeners because there is a proxy to redirect requests to the broker. Anyway until some weeks ago everything worked fine...

My step to start kafka:

```
1- service zookeeper start 
2- ./kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0/bin/kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0/config/server.properties
```

Any advises?
Thank you

Answer (score 58):

uncomment this line

```
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

changed this to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Comment: sometimes add below as well                                                         listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092                              advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092                                                                                   dont forget to delete all the logs in zookeeper and kafka

Comment: The default is to use the local machine hostname, so inserting `127.0.0.1` would have the same effect.

Answer (score 30):

I also had the same issue...

So I start by asking Zookeeper some data

```
echo dump | nc localhost 2181
```

I get back something like this

```
SessionTracker dump:
Session Sets (3):
0 expire at Sun Dec 03 18:15:48 GST 2017:
0 expire at Sun Dec 03 18:15:51 GST 2017:
1 expire at Sun Dec 03 18:15:54 GST 2017:
0x1601c9a25190000
ephemeral nodes dump:
Sessions with Ephemerals (1):
0x1601c9a25190000:
/controller
/brokers/ids/0
```

I read this to mean that I have 1 Broker available - and it is has an id of 0.

So, lets find about that broker.

```
bin/zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 <<< "get /brokers/ids/0"
```

And I see

```
{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.220:9092"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"192.168.1.220","timestamp":"1512308520781","port":9092,"version":4}
cZxid = 0x69
ctime = Sun Dec 03 17:42:00 GST 2017
mZxid = 0x69
mtime = Sun Dec 03 17:42:00 GST 2017
pZxid = 0x69
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x1601c9a25190000
dataLength = 196
numChildren = 0
```

This rather startled me ... **PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.220:9092**, so when I changed my connect string to read

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh  --broker-list PLAINTEXT://192.168.1.220:9092  --topic test
```

It all now worked.

Good luck !!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was stuck on this problem and was about to reinstall kafka.

Comment: You are the best. Stuck for like 3 hours trying to figure out what's wrong)

Answer (score 13):

We faced the same situation, when we started to search the logs for the actual cause of the error.

When we were starting the Kafka cluster, it was using by default

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

to connect and was not able to find the host.

We changed the line to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<our ip address> :9092,
```

then

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://<our ip address> :9093,
```

in our server-1.properties ( another broker id file ) and the same we replicated in other server.properties file and restarted our cluster.

Comment: I did same thing but it is not working for me. getting below error [2018-12-27 21:13:27,169] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroup] Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: Did you checked the server.log to find the reason.
is there any additional spaces between the address ?

Comment: Yes I have checked. there are no spaces between address. Actually I was checking kafka fault tolerance by killing first node manually on my local multi node cluster.

Comment: Did you try to rebalance ?

Answer (score 5):

i configed the kafka server.properties's listener as `listeners=PLAINTEXT://**10.127.96.151**:9092`

but i request the consumer as `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server **localhost**:9092 --topic topic1 --from-beginning` , then it bursts the WARNs.

when i fix the consumer bootstrap-server as **10.127.96.151**:9092, it runs all well with no more WARNs

Comment: why 10.127.96.151 ? it that your static ip?

Comment: @Razvan yes, it's my ip, a example. you can replace it with your ip.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by setting the listeners property in Kafka in WSL2 to the IPv6 loopback address:

In `kafka_2.13-3.5.1/config/kraft/server.properties` for KRaft-mode, or `kafka_2.13-3.5.1/config/server.properties` for Zookeeper-mode, change:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
```

to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://[::1]:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
```

and to advertise the same address to the consumers:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
```

to

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://[::1]:9092
```

The property default values are slightly different in the two property files. Just adapt the IP part.
I posted the KRaft `server.properties` to highlight that the `CONTROLLER:`-part should stay untouched.

And for the Java application, the property respectively:

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=[::1]:9092
```

Credits to
https://docs.conduktor.io/desktop/kafka-cluster-connection/setting-up-a-connection-to-kafka/connecting-to-kafka-running-on-windows-wsl-2/#two-ways-to-fix-this
where I found the basics for the IPv6 solution, just had to extend it a bit for the KRaft-mode.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem on WINDOWS 10 and went through all the answers in this post. What caused this problem for me and how I solved is this,
On my fresh windows machine, I did a jre (jre-8u221) installation and then followed the steps mentioned in Apache Kafka documentation to start zookeeper, kafka server, send messages through producer etc. But I was getting errors related to broker not available.
I then downloaded jdk (jdk-8u221 from Oracle) and installed it. Set the JAVA_HOME and Path variables and restarted the machine. Everything after worked in one go.

Answer (score 1):

I server.propertes:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://hidden_ip:9092
```

when I run:
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic lt1
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic lt1`
I get same error just like you get.and I try run :

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list hidden_ip:9092 --topic lt1
```

it work,I get no error.
So i think you should check what's port kafka server used.This error when port is not esestablished or you connect wrong ip.
PS:I run this on same machine.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same issue where everything was working fine and just stopped working one day. I backtracked my changes surrounding the Kafka initial set up and figured out below are steps that needs to be taken to fix this

1. Make sure that your JDK is installed correctly. I exactly had the issue because the JDK path/JAVA_HOME path I was pointing to was incorrect due to which even when the broker started it was not detected by the Client.
2. If then also nothing works out, then go for

#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
changed this to

listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

**or**

listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

Answer (score 0):

```
error message: "Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available"
```

Solution:

I was getting this error because I was having a different version of kafka running on cluster vs local. Make sure the version is the same. I was specifying the version in `pom.xml` under `properties` tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, please see if the below property is set in `application.properties` file, assuming a producer application only:

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
```

Otherwise, the following should work in general:

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
```

I didn’t have to change `listeners` in the `server.properties` file, as others have proposed.

Answer (score 0):

With spring-boot, kafka (image: spotify/kafka) and docker-compose combination, you might need to set below property in project:

```
broker-addresses: <hostname>:9092
```

Also, the services in docker-compose need to have environment property configured as below,

```
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: <hostname>:9092
```

Hope this might helps someone.

Comment: `spotify/kafka` image has not been updated in years

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is solved by now but I was getting this on a Kafka client running on an AWS ECS task trying to connect to a Kafka cluster running on EC2 instances and the problem was the security groups. Adding the CIDRS of all ECS task's allowed subnets (ECS -> cluster -> task -> details -> allowed subents) in the list of inbound rules for the cluster (ec2 -> instances -> security -> (select your security group) -> edit inbound rules -> (custom TCP/9092/CIDR) -> Add Rule) solved the issue.

Comment: I am using spring boot with kafka in local it is workig fine . but at aws msk it is not getting connected and giving error "Broker may not be available" I have set  bootstrap.servers : we need to map broker url ,b1-xyz:9094,b2-xyz:9094,b3-xyz:9094 right?need to add zookeeper url also? and where we need to add cluster name ?

Comment: if possible please share sample code to connect aws msk cluster from local

Comment: As far as I can tell you are using a different setup. MSK is quite different that deploying your own Kafka cluster on EC2 instances so I'm not sure how relatable your situation is.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue When I was learning kafka. In my case found that I didn't started the zookeeper and kafka server. Due to that broker may not be available error was showing.
So After starting both zookeeper and kafka server the problem was resolved.

start zookeeper:

```
zookeeper-server-start.sh ~/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/config/zookeeper.properties
```

start Kafka:

```
kafka-server-start.sh ~/kafka_2.13-3.1.0/config/server.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Windows and have used **WSL/WSL2(Ubuntu/Linux)** to deploy kafka server then try to **disable ipv6**

#I had to disable WSL2 ipv6 for kafka and other services running and being accesible to my local spring project

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1